# Calculating the leaking current for a tantalum capacitor

Tags: capacitor, datasheet, tantalum

I've been looking [at these tantalum caps](http://www.kemet.com/Lists/ProductCatalog/Attachments/260/KEM_T2030_T522.pdf) for a coin cell operated BLE device, but I'm a little confused by specified leakage current.  The datasheet lists the leakage current at <= 0.003CV uA.  With a 470uA cap at 6.0V, my calculated leakage current is 0.003 * 0.000470 * 6.0, which is 0.00000846.  The datasheet says that current is in uA.

Is the leakage current *really* 0.00000846uA?  Or is the C (capacitive) value in the equation supposed to be in uF, not F?  That would make more sense if the leakage current was 8.46uA, although that seems high for a "low leakage" cap.

And yes, I am well aware of the potential dangers of tantalums.  Operating voltage is going to be in the 3.0V - 2.0V range.  We have a few other (highly experienced) EEs working on this project, and I'm trying to get up the learning curve on some aspects of datasheet specs.

Comment: For double checking if some values make sense, you can always measure.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Unfortunately, I don't have tantalum caps nearby to try out.  Good point, though.

Comment: Try another supplier of similar device to see what they say.

Comment: My 0.02, I would assume the same thing as you, they ment either C in uF or really 0.003CV in A.

Comment: A few uA of leakage for a tantalum cap seems realistic. Tantalum have relatively high leakage. Ceramic would have much less, but of course, you can't have such a high capacitance value with ceramic. By the way, are you sure you need such a high capacitance somewhere in a battery-operated device? Seems strange to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula from the datasheet is leakage = 0.03CV

If you use the capacitance in Farads, then at 6V you have 84.6uA

Table 1 in the datasheet states the maximum leakage for the 470uF cap at 25C is 89uA.

Comment: Unless you have a guarantee of leakage current, it can be very scattered part-to-part.  Measuring won't help unless you measure a lot of them.  Then you can do a probability curve.

Comment: Wow.  Can't believe I missed that table in the datasheet.